# Decouple page name from page title

Tags: custom-field, pages, admin, title, quick-edit

As far as I can see, the name of a page (in admin) is the same as the title for the page.

In many cases you would want the page name to be something else to better grasp what it's about while glancing through the page admin. Perhaps you have a page with the title "This is what it is when it all comes around",  which could be tagd as the "about" page and thus want it to be called "about" in the page listing in admin.

Yes, you could add a custom field for another title but I think that would be backwards and not user friendly.

Perhaps an additional name-field in quick-edit which will override the name (not title) of the page in admin? In the above case with page named "This is what it is when it all comes around", you would just quick-edit the page and enter "about" in the name field.

Other ideas?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Oh, will clarify

Comment: "Yes, you could add a custom field for another title but I think that would be backwards and not user friendly." -- you've already eliminated the answer. What other solution are you hoping for?

Comment: "Would it be possible to have an additional field in quick edit, called for example name?", "Other ideas?" Is my question and, if you will, what I'm hoping for.

Comment: Right, but unless you hack the WordPress Core your option is a custom meta field whether that is a meta box on the edit screen or an extra field in the quick edit menu (if possible, I'd have to research).

Comment: Yeah, that would be awesome!

Comment: We have a whole tag on how to edit that, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quick-edit

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the `the_title` calls from your theme and inserting the title as an H1 into the text. This way you truly decouple things.

Comment: I'd say this is bad user UX

Comment: how is this related in any way to UX?

Comment: If I get you right this would remove the title field in the editor, no?

Comment: no, just from the theme files. The user then will have to put the title as a h1 in the beginning of the content, and the title in the title box will be used in the admin to identify the page and for title tag in the HTML. Frankly I never understood why WP forces people to have a title as part of the content, for example facebook doesn't do it